# onerror parameter in ant <taskdef>/<typedef> in antlib descriptor

Tags: java, ant

I am creating an antlib with custom tasks to be used in our build system.

I have looked at [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) antlib declaration and noticed that the typedefs/taskdefs have `onerror` parameter set to `ignore`, e.g.

```
<taskdef
    name="for"
    classname="net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask"
    onerror="ignore"/>
```

The default value of the `onerror` parameter is `fail`.

I have 2 questions:

- Why ant-contrib authors use `ignore?`
- Should I use `ignore` in my antlib declaration, or `fail` is just fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our project we (among many other things) run our unittests through ant. If the task stopped on error, we would only be able to solve errors in our unittests sequentially one build after another. Letting the process finish even with errors gives us an overview of all the errors that arose in our test suites.